# Reading data from a text file, comparing lines & displaying in preferred format

Tags: java, string, parsing, file-io

I am reading a text file which contains the log in and out values of an employees,
and trying to display in single line bot in and out values which are in different line for same employee and date.the data in that text file is as shown below.

```
line 1. 02,-"sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61
line 2. 01,-"lohith-May 01, 2013 , -out-09:10:41:61
line 3. 02,-"sushma-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61
line 4. 01,-"sushma-Jan 01, 2013 , -in-09:07:06:50-out-05:39:01:63
line 5. 02,-"sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -out-08:08:19:27
line 6. 02,-"sushma-May 02, 2013 , -out-07:52:13:51
line 7. 03,-"lohith-May 03, 2013 , -in-11:39:44:08
```

example: line 1 and line5 are in and out values for same employee sangeetha, so it should display like:

```
02,-"sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61, -out-08:08:19:27
```

Perhaps I am getting this output, but line 2, it don't have in value, so my code is not able to displaying that only which ever employee having both in and out values in different like its displaying those. I want to display theses records also with missing message appended to it..my code is this..

```
public class RecordParser {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RecordParser rp = new RecordParser();
    rp.recordFormatter("sample.txt");
  }

  public static void recordFormatter(String filename) {

    try {
      BufferedReader in;
      List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
      String line = "";
      String line1;
      String line2;
      String lines;
      String mergedRecords = "";
      String normalRecords = "";
      String halfRecords = "";
      in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        ls.add(line);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
        line1 = ls.get(i);
        if (line1.contains("in") && line1.contains("out")) {
          normalRecords += line1;
          normalRecords += System.getProperty("line.separator");
          // ls.remove(i);
          // break;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ls.size(); j++) {
          line2 = ls.get(j);
          if (line2.contains("in") && line2.contains("out"))
            continue;
          if (line1.contains(getNameDate(line2))) {
            mergedRecords += line1
                + line2.substring(line2.lastIndexOf(","), line2.length());
            mergedRecords += System.getProperty("line.separator");
            // ls.remove(i);
            // ls.remove(i);
            break;
          }
          if (!line1.contains(getNameDate(line2))) {
            if (!mergedRecords.contains(getNameDate(line1))) {
              halfRecords += line1;
              halfRecords += System.getProperty("line.separator");
            }
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println(mergedRecords);
      System.out.println(normalRecords);
      System.out.println(halfRecords);
      // && line2.contains("out") && line1.contains("in")
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static String getNameDate(String input) {
    return input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf(","));
  }
}
```

Please can anybody modify it to show records which are having only either in entry or out entry?

For example..line 2 should display like:

```
line 2. 01,-"lohith-May 01, 2013 ,missing in, -out-09:10:41:61..
```

Presently I am getting output is:

```
02,-"sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61, -out-08:08:19:27
02,-"sushma-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61-out-07:52:13:51
01,-"sushma-Jan 01, 2013 , -in-09:07:06:50-out-05:39:01:63
```

I want that line 2 record to display with these.

Comment: Sure, anything else we can do for you?  Maybe you'd like some coffee or a bagel?

Comment: it's because in value for lohits is coming after out value in terms of lines, so you should either move the line with -in value to above -out line or you should make your code line-agnostic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is that it is one monolithic mess.  It's hard to see where you're going wrong.

I put together some code to process your input.  The reason I wrote this code is to show you and the others reading this later how to break monolithic code into tiny, testable pieces.

Not including the input string I created (since you have an input file), there is no method in this code longer than 20 lines.  Some are much shorter.

I ran this code three times.  The first time, I forgot to code the output method.  The second time, I had to correct the output format.  The third time, I produced this output.

```
02,-"sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61 , -out-08:08:19:27
01,-"lohith-May 01, 2013 , missing in , -out-09:10:41:61
02,-"sushma-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61 , -out-07:52:13:51
01,-"sushma-Jan 01, 2013 , -in-09:07:06:50 , -out-05:39:01:63
03,-"lohith-May 03, 2013 , -in-11:39:44:08 , missing out
```

And here's the code.  Study it and learn.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecordParser {

    private BufferedReader reader;

    private List<Person> people;

    private List<String> output;

    public RecordParser(BufferedReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        this.output = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void execute() throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split(" , ");
            addPerson(new Person(parts[0]));
            if ((parts[1].contains("-in-")) && (parts[1].contains("-out-"))) {
                String[] inout = parts[1].split("-out-");
                Person person = getPerson(parts[0]);
                person.setInTime(inout[0]);
                person.setOutTime("-out-" + inout[1]);
            } else if (parts[1].contains("-in-")) {
                Person person = getPerson(parts[0]);
                person.setInTime(parts[1]);
            } else {
                Person person = getPerson(parts[0]);
                person.setOutTime(parts[1]);
            }
        }

        // Output the people to the String list
        for (Person p : people) {
            output.add(p.getPerson());
        }
    }

    private void addPerson(Person person) {
        for (Person p : people) {
            if (p.getNameDate().equals(person.getNameDate())) {
                return;
            }
        }
        people.add(person);
    }

    private Person getPerson(String nameDate) {
        for (Person p : people) {
            if (p.getNameDate().equals(nameDate)) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<String> getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "02,-\"sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61\n" +
                "01,-\"lohith-May 01, 2013 , -out-09:10:41:61\n" +
                "02,-\"sushma-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61\n" +
                "01,-\"sushma-Jan 01, 2013 , -in-09:07:06:50-out-05:39:01:63\n" +
                "02,-\"sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -out-08:08:19:27\n" +
                "02,-\"sushma-May 02, 2013 , -out-07:52:13:51\n" +
                "03,-\"lohith-May 03, 2013 , -in-11:39:44:08";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input));
        RecordParser recordParser = new RecordParser(reader);

        try {
            recordParser.execute();

            for (String s : recordParser.getOutput()) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class Person {
        private String nameDate;
        private String inTime;
        private String outTime;

        public Person (String nameDate) {
            this.nameDate = nameDate;
            this.inTime = "missing in";
            this.outTime = "missing out";
        }

        public void setInTime(String inTime) {
            this.inTime = inTime;
        }

        public void setOutTime(String outTime) {
            this.outTime = outTime;
        }

        public String getNameDate() {
            return nameDate;
        }

        public String getPerson() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(nameDate);
            builder.append(" , ");
            builder.append(inTime);
            builder.append(" , ");
            builder.append(outTime);
            return builder.toString();
        }

    }

}
```